# How to make 'less' not take full terminal

Tags: shell, unix, terminal, cygwin

I have quick question but I can not find an answer to it.

How one can make 'less' program not take full terminal layout. What I mean, is how to display file using `less` on upper half of terminal for example? Is it possible to achieve that? How does 'less' know how many lines current terminal have?

**Use case:**
`git log --graph` uses `less` as a pager. I have three lines prompt. Every time I quit `git log` command, terminal displays new prompt lines and scrolls `git log` output up. In most of the time the three scrolled lines are the most important lines, so I need to scroll it manually to be able to copy them for future use. So I am trying to find a way to tell 'less' to use half of the terminal, or full terminal without last three lines, so when I quit `git log`, the new prompt won't hide upper lines. Is there a way to do that?

Target environment: cygwin

Comment: `git log | less` will not overwrite bash output, but do not have color.(Test on ubuntu)

Comment: Not sure I fully understand the use case?

Answer (score 4):

You can use GNU [`screen`](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) or [`tmux`](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) or the ancient BSD [`window(1)`](https://www.mirbsd.org/man1/window) utility to subdivide the screen into sections and move between them.

I just tested [`less(1)`](https://www.mirbsd.org/man1/less) in `window`, and it works, although the status line is no longer reversed. You get much better results in GNU screen (industry standard) or tmux (newcomer).

Answer (score 2):

I have a horrible hack that sort-of works but before I get to that you can always just start copying the lines before you exit from less and avoid this problem entirely.

Horrible hacky workaround:

```
LESS='FRSX -j 4 -p ^' git log --graph
```

where `4` is the offset you want at the top of the window.

The trick here is that you tell less to keep a given offset for searched lines and search for something that matches the first line to force it to scroll down.

You can probably do this in `core.pager` with `less -j 4 -p ^` but I haven't tried it and I don't know that I would recommend it either.

Comment: As for 'first page' preview, this workaround is useful. Until you start to scroll... ;) better this than nothing, thank you

Comment: It works for any line you search for but will not prevent you from scrolling the line you need to the top that is true. The better solution is to copy before quitting less and/or not using such a verbose prompt. =)

Answer (score 1):

Another hacky solution is to use tput.

```
git config --global core.pager "less; tput cuu 1 && tput ed"
```

This actually works after you scroll. If you want this to work for long PS1 wrapping just make it go back 2 instead of 1.

Comment: This actually doesn't work on cygwin (from my testing), but it does work on msys2.

Comment: Wow, this helps a lot with git and hg :-)

Comment: I add an issue for that https://github.com/gwsw/less/issues/84

Comment: The current solution overwrite the last lines when you scrolled to the end within the less-pager. This can be avoided when you append two lines before piping the git output to less-pager with: `"(cat; echo; echo) | less; tput cuu 2 && tput ed"`

Answer (score -1):

Set the `LINES` environment variable

```
export LINES=3
command | less
```

Comment: `Linux` says the `LINES` variable is read-only. This may be similar on `Cygwin` (the OP's desired environment) but not on `OS X`.

Comment: The shell may be resetting LINES before each command, but `env LINES=3 less` will reliably set it for the `less` process.  _However_, it doesn't affect less for me, it's probably getting screen size from terminal directly.